# How to take union of matrix rows that are represented by another vector?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, set-union

I want to take the union of some of the rows of a matrix `x`. The row numbers of the rows whose union has to be taken are given by vector `r`. Is there any built-in function in MATLAB that can do it?

```
x = [1  2  4  0  0; 
     3  6  5  0  0;
     7  8 10 12  9;
     2  4  6  7  0;
     3  4  5  8 12];

r = [1, 3, 5];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work for you - first, take the submatrix `x(r,:)` with the rows you want, and then find all the unique values in it:

```
unique(x(r,:))

ans =
     0
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     7
     8
     9
    10
    12
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
>>> union(union(x(r(1),:),x(r(2),:)),x(r(3),:))

ans =

  0     1     2     3     4     5     7     8     9    10    12
```

or set up a `for` loop that iterates over the vector `r` to compute all the unions